# Importing a SVG file creates too many faces

Tags: import, path

I am trying to import a simple SVG shape into Blender to extrude and bevel it, but the result looks very complex / has too many faces.

[image]

I've found other tutorials for SVG import that had the same problems, but no precise answer or explanation as to how to avoid this.

I am trying to import the outside path to bevel it as seen on this illustration:

[image]

Comment: Another option is adding a *Decimate Modifier* on top of your converted geometry and clean it up manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SVG importer likely generates a 2D curve initially, so in future you might be better off to avoid converting to a Mesh first. Some steps below can be skipped if you do that.

Like this:

[image]

There's a few ways to do this, the simplest might be to simply ignore the fact that you have a lot of faces, and convert straight into 2D Curve

[image]

- Convert the Mesh in Object mode to Curve using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
- Set to 2D Curve type.
  [image]
- Use the Geometry panel to adjust offset / extrude and bevel depth. The Curve object has a lot of the same features as the Font Object type.

  [image]

Comment: Importing a SVG should create curves.

Comment: yep, that means OP can either redo to get back to Curve and skip the first steps or use what he has and follow these steps.

Comment: Thanks again for the great answer, @zeffii ! Do you know if there's a way to "apply" extrusion and bevel, to make what we see a real 3D shape?

Comment: @fabriced you want a mesh and don't need to make any more edits to the shape? then in Object mode , with the object active, press Alt+C and pick `Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text`. Feel free to ask a fresh question to get comprehensive answers.